# How to get rid of "Analytics Education" when logging into Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Each time I open Google Analytics reporting view, I am presented with their "Analytics Education" pop in:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AeqeHqf.png]

How to have this pop in closed by default please?

Comment: How about the little x in the upper right-hand corner next to the right & left arrows?

Comment: I can close it, but next time I visit the page (or refresh it) it is opened again.

Comment: This may sound a bit strange, and I would not know what specifically to look for, but maybe there is a cookie that dictates this behavior. I have not seen this dialog box (lack of a better term) before. Also, perhaps dumping the browser cache. I would not recommend deleting cookies through your browser unless you decide that it is okay to go through the agro of setting various preferences again. Not sure this will work. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "Graduation Cap" button is toggled on.  Try toggling that off.

I was able to replicate your issue by clicking that button, moving to another report view, then returning to the previous view.  Analytics Education was still on.  Toggling the button to 'off' solved the issue for me.

Comment: This doesn't help for me, the content is back after next pageload/refresh

Answer (score 0):

[closetnoc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/36029/closetnoc) has the solution in his comment.   Close the message with the `X` in the corner:

[image]

Comment: I asked how to have it closed by "default". If I close it and refresh the page, it opens again.

Comment: I closed that at some point and it didn't come back.    I guess that just using the X is not sufficient.